# Notification problems in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

I've just installed eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 and every time I open eclipse I get this error:

```
An internal error occurred during "Fetch all notifications"
An internal error occurred during: "Fetch all notifications".
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
An internal error occurred during: "Get notification settings URL".
Could not initialize class com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.notifications.model.NotificationsService
```

The pplugins installed are vaadin and svn. I'm not having this kind of problem on another machine, although that runs on WIndow, but I'm not sure whether I left anything off...any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Sign-in the vaadin account for the notification feeds at the bottom right (bell icon) and the problem will go away.